# Why is the minimal bolt edge distance not affected by plate thickness?

Tags: bolting

[image]

Eurocode specifies minimum distances from a bolt hole to the edge of the plate. But why is the bolt diameter the only relevant parameter? Why isn't the minimal distance also a function of the plate thickness? Intuitively, I would think that with a thicker plate we could place a bolt closer to the edge since there is more area perpendicular to the force affecting the bolts.

Comment: But how are the loads applied?

Comment: If the Eurocode offers a commentary, I'd look there to see if the basis of the provision is explained. In the AISC specification, the minimum edge distance is a workmanship standard related to fabrication tolerances. Bolt bearing and tear-out are separate design checks that do include plate thickness in the calculations.

Comment: It's actually determined from the *hole* diameter. It's a tear-out thing. It's based on the shear area leading away from the hole. The hole will egg before the plate fails in shear. Nonstandard fasteners may have different requirements.